# An internal error occurred during: "Launching counter" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, eclipse

I am now using API-21 in eclipse adt. Whenever I am trying to run any program I am getting this error message.

Firstly,

> parseSdkContent failed
>   Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface

2nd one,

> 'An internal error occurred during: "Launching counter".
>   java.lang.NullPointerException'

I have searched about this issues. I have already tried deleting .android from users folder and switching workspace. Should I move to any previous API versions ?  I am really struggling at this API-21. New issues are coming every day. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the SDK platform for API 20 (4.4W)

Navigate to your sdk folder (should be like D:\EclipseWorkspace\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk)

Go to platforms folder -> android-21 folder -> data folder

rename layoutlib.jar (for backup purpose)

copy the same file (layoutlib.jar) from your android-20 folder to this folder

restart Eclipse

Comment: It's working now. Thanks a lot. But I'm not getting what's wrong with the updated version of adt. I am getting a new error every single day.